# Changing iAd position and placement

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, iad, ios5

I've been looking at various tutorials and code snippets, try to implement iAd. I've been successful to an extent but I need to customise, I can't seem to work out what I need to do to make my changes, can anyone help?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
[self.view addSubview:adView];
adView.delegate = self;
self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    // banner is invisible now and moved out of the screen on 50 px
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
if (self.bannerIsVisible)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    // banner is visible and we move it out of the screen, due to connection issue
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
}
```

As it stands, the banners are loaded at the top of a UIWebView. Firstly I'd like it at the bottom and secondly, the ad overlaps the WebView content, is there any way I can push the WebView when an ad loads or disappears?

I'd appreciate any help, this is driving round the bend!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

set adview.frame.origin.y to however far bottom you want it, **when** you want it. For instance, my iad is setup in the app delegate, then in the view controller I want, in viewwillapear, I'd use adview.frame.origin.x = 0;adview.frame.origin.y = 420; [SharediAdView setframe:adview.frame];

with diff settings depending on iphone 3.5inch/4inch, space in the current view controller, & orientation.

If you'd rather move everything up/down, and don't want to mess with a tailored solution, I'd try this stuff: https://github.com/chrisjp/CJPAdController

Answer (score 0):

```
adView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 375.0, iAdView.frame.size.width, iAdView.frame.size.height);
```

Use this code instead of

```
adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
```

and change Ad placement (375.0) according to what you want :)